# Query to retrieve defects from parent and children

Tags: rally

I have inherited code that displays a graph of defects on a project. I have now took my project and split it into two projects, so that now there is a parent project and two children. The code (below) just accumulates the defects from the parent and does not include the data from the children.

snippet:

```
storeType: "Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore", 
                storeConfig: { 
                    find: { _TypeHierarchy: "Defect", Children: null }, 
                    fetch: ["Severity", "State"], hydrate: ["Severity", "State"], 
                    sort: { _ValidFrom: 1 }, 
                    filters: [{ property: "Project", value: context.getProject().ObjectID }, { property: "_TypeHierarchy", value: "Defect" }, { property: "Children", value: null}] },
```

So I'm pretty sure the problem is in this part "value: context.getProject().ObjectID" as it says to get the data from the current project (and not its children). How can I accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're intending to get lookback (time series) data or current (WSAPI) data from Rally. Your code implies lookback so I will answer with that in mind.

You could try adding to your find clause (and removing the current Project filter):

"_ProjectHierarchy": { $in : [123] }

where 123 is the object id of your parent project. That should get defects from any projects that include you parent project in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, will be sure to try. Can you first tell me how do I find my project id?

Comment: From your question it sounded like you were already getting the parent project id with the call context.getProject().ObjectID. Is that not the case?

Comment: So I tried the below and it didn't work (it gives me data regarding all bugs in all projects I have access to). Tall me if you think I'm doing it wrong?

storeConfig: { 
 find: [{ _TypeHierarchy: "Defect", Children: null }, {property: "_ProjectHierarchy", value: context.getProject().ObjectID }], 
 fetch: ["Severity", "State"], hydrate: ["Severity", "State"], 
 sort: { _ValidFrom: 1 }, 
 filters: [ { property: "_TypeHierarchy", value: "Defect" }, { property: "Children", value: null}] },

Comment: Try this: `find: {_TypeHierarchy: "Defect", _ProjectHierarchy: context.getProject().ObjectID, "__At": "current"}, fetch: ["Severity", "State"], hydrate: ["Severity", "State"], sort: { _ValidFrom: 1 }`. Children: null is redundant for defects as they won't have any children and I don't think you need the filter. Note that this will get all the defects for the parent project and all of its children projects, which may be more than just the two you mentioned in the original question. Also I added __At: current as I think you are trying to get the latest version of the defect and not all revisions

Answer (score 0):

So Igor basically got it above, just writing as a post and not in a commet, this is the code that works - you can see why in the comments above. Please note - I did make one change over what he wrote, as when I used the "__At" it caused not all bugs to be counted - it looked like it only counted bugs since their last update time.

```
storeConfig: { 
                    find: { _TypeHierarchy: "Defect", _ProjectHierarchy: context.getProject().ObjectID}, 
                    fetch: ["Severity", "State"], hydrate: ["Severity", "State"], 
                    sort: { _ValidFrom: 1 }, 
                     },
```