# Query to create burndown from parent and children

Tags: rally

This question is related to another question of mine: [Query to retrieve defects from parent and children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456944/query-to-retrieve-defects-from-parent-and-children/30570576#30570576)
I have inherited code that displays a burndown of a project. I have now took my project and split it into two projects, so that now there is a parent project and two children. The code (below) fails to create any burndown, I assume this is because it cannot find any stories/tasks on top-level project, and (I assume) it is not looking at the children project. 
Please note - the solution in the link I refer to did not work for me here (removed the children: null and replaced with _ProjectHierarchy: context.getProject().ObjectID,)

Anyway - here's the code:

```
storeConfig: { 
                    find: { _TypeHierarchy: "HierarchicalRequirement"}, 
                    fetch: ["TaskEstimateTotal", "TaskRemainingTotal", "Iteration"], hydrate: ["TaskEstimateTotal", "TaskRemainingTotal", "Iteration"], 
                    sort: { _ValidFrom: 1 }, 
                    filters: [{ property: "Iteration", value: iterationRecord.get("ObjectID") }, { property: "_TypeHierarchy", value: "HierarchicalRequirement"}] 
                    },
```

Comment: This is one of the more-complicated things to do with the lookback API.  You're filtering on a single iteration oid, but iteration oids are distinct for every project.  Put another way, if all three of the projects in your scenario have an iteration with the same name, start date and end date, then there are three different oids you need to filter on in order to find all data for all three projects.

Comment: So the difficulty is because they have different iteration objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore your hierarchy by adding this to your find:

```
_ProjectHierarchy: 12345
```

where 12345 is the object id of your parent project.

Additionally, what Joel mentioned above is also true.  In Rally there is a concept of "like iterations", where in a project hierarchy there are similarly named/dated iterations for each project.

So you'll just have to add the following to your find clause to make sure your results are filtered to all the child iterations:

```
Iteration: {$in: [23456, 34567]}
```

where 23456 and 34567 are the object id's of the iterations for the child projects.

You can use a simple Rally.data.wsapi.Store to load all the "like iterations" for whatever period you're interested in reporting on and then grab the object id's to pass into your chart storeConfig.